# How to chose guard for session driver

Tags: laravel, session, guard

I'm trying to create a login page with laravel web route. When user login, a session record will be saved to database. But in session table, `user_id` always get `null` value.
I've found that in `Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler`, function `userId()` always return `null`. It's because I set default `guard` for `api`. This is my `config/auth.php`:

```
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

When I change default guard to `web`, column `user_id` in database has value is authorized user id. I don't want to change my default guard to `web`.

How can I set guard driver for session? Is there something like `Auth`, we can use `Auth::guard('web')`.

Thanks

Comment: 'api' is usually used for stateless api's which is why that guard doesn't use sessions by default ... why do you not want to use the 'web' guard (considering you want sessions)?

Comment: Another part of my website using ```api``` as default, so I don't want to change those part.

Comment: if you are already using a guard named 'api' that is configured how you want then you wouldn't want to go in and alter that guard ... you sound like you need to be using 2 different guards so where you need to use the other guard you just have to be explicit with it, `Auth::guard('web')->....`  (if it isn't the default you would have to access it like that, but you can adjust the default at run time)

Comment: I've already used ```Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials)``` for login, it works perfectly but in session table, ```user_id``` always be null.

Answer (score -1):

Typically, API's are not associated with keeping session state between requests.

You can always add additional groups with seperate guards to the same routes and use them according to your needs. E.g.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::post('/user', 'UserController@apiUser');
}

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::post('/user', 'UserController@index');
}
```

and then seperately reference

```
$user = auth('web')->user();
```

or

```
$user = auth('api')->user();
```

Read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport) for a Laravel API implementation using Passport. You may also want to consider [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum) which offers support for API token generation for your users.

Comment: I've already used ```Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials)``` for login, it works perfectly but in session table, ```user_id``` always be null